# Let µ be counting measure on $B_{\mathbb{R}}$. Then prove there exists no finite measure $\lambda$ on $B_{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $\mu \ll \lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

My question statement is:  If we have that $\mu$ is a counting measure on $B_{\mathbb{R}}$, then prove there is no finite measure $\lambda$ on $B_{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $\mu \ll \lambda.$

We know that the measure of any finite set is the number of elements in the set, and the measure of any infinite set is then infinity.  So this measure is not $\sigma-$finite.  I'm not sure how else to proceed and am curious if someone could provide me with assistance.

Comment: Regarding your deleted comment/answer: Yes. Basically, assume that there is an uncountable family $M$ of pairwise disjoint sets of positive measure. Let $M_n = \{A \in M \mid \lambda(A) > 1/n\}$ and note $M = \bigcup_n M_n$. I will let you continue from here.

Answer (score 2):

Show that if there was such a measure $\lambda$, we would necessarily have $\lambda(\{x\}) > 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$.

Show that for a finite measure, there can not be uncountably many pairwise disjoint sets of positive measure.

Further hint:

> Order the sets with positive measure in those that have measure $ > 1/n$ for each $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that for a space $X$ with a finite measure $\lambda$, the set $\{ x \in X \ | \ \lambda(\{x\}) > 0\}$ is countable. Indeed, it is the union of the sets $\{ x \in X \ | \ \lambda(\{x\}) > \frac{1}{n}\}$ and each such set has cardinality $< \frac{\lambda(X)}{n}$ .

$\bf{Added:}$ The above is also true if $\lambda$ is only assumed to be $\sigma$-finite.

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is ucountable, for any finite (Borel) measure $\lambda$ there exist (uncountably many) $x$ such that $\lambda(\{x\}) = 0$.